# ASP.NET Routing and Regular Expressions

Tags: asp.net, routes

I am trying to enable a route like the following

```
route = new Route("{w1}-{c1}-{n1},{w2}-{c2}-{n2}", new ResultRouteHandler());
route.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
route.Constraints.Add("c1", "(.*)|([-])");
route.Constraints.Add("c2", "(.*)|([-])");
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
```

However I run into a problem when c1 or c2 is "-". For example "a-b-c,d---f" returns 404 (whilst "a-b-c,d-e-f" works fine). Anyone has a clue what am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I found a simple workaround for this problem:

```
route = new Route("{w1}-{c1}-{n1},{w2}---{n2}", new MyRouteHandler());
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
route = new Route("{w1}-{c1}-{n1},{w2}-{c2}-{n2}", new MyRouteHandler());
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
```

If c2 is "-" we match to the first route, otherwise to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you **do** want to match `"a-b-c,d---f"` which is why you're tweaking the constraints in the first place.  The Regex you have there is kind of redundant though as `'-'` will be matched by the `'.*'`.  In other words, I don't think your Regex is to blame but rather the routing engine parser.

If you change your route from `"{w1}-{c1}-{n1},{w2}-{c2}-{n2}"` to `"{w1}-{c1}-{n1},{w2}_{c2}-{n2}"`, then c2 will start matching the `'-'` in `"a-b-c,d_--f"`.  I think something about the parsing of routes doesn't like using a delimiter as the next value.

So I think you can drop your constraints (as they currently exist), but you might need to organize your URLs a little differently if you want `'-'` to be `c1` or `c2`.

Comment: Yep it seems to be not possible to create the rule with a single route, due to the way Regex is parsed. I worked around the problem by having two routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% positive about the regex implementation, but it should look like this I think:

```
route.Constraints.Add("c1", "([^-]*)");
route.Constraints.Add("c2", "([^-]*)");
```